# Knife-solo warning local cookbook path

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, knife-solo

When using knife-solo, I've got this warning: "Local cookbook_path '/Users/username/chef-test/cookbooks' does not exist", and cookbooks directory is removed before I knew it.
Removing Berksfile, I have no warning message.

> $ knife -v
>   Chef: 12.0.0
>   $ gem list | grep knife
>   knife-solo (0.4.2)
>   $ knife solo init .
>   Creating kitchen...
>   Creating knife.rb in kitchen...
>   Creating cupboards...
>   Setting up Berkshelf...
>   $ ls -al
>   total 32
>   drwxr-xr-x  13 username  staff   442 12  7 19:11 .
>   drwxr-xr-x+ 26 username  staff   884 12  7 19:09 ..
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 .chef
>   -rw-r--r--   1 username  staff    12 12  7 19:11 .gitignore
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 21:52 .vagrant
>   -rw-r--r--   1 username  staff    41 12  7 00:34 Berksfile
>   -rw-r--r--   1 username  staff  4818 12  6 21:52 Vagrantfile
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  7 19:11 cookbooks
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 data_bags
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 environments
>   drwxr-xr-x   4 username  staff   136 12  7 19:09 nodes
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 roles
>   drwxr-xr-x   6 username  staff   204 12  7 01:48 site-cookbooks
>   $ knife solo cook webdb
>   Running Chef on webdb...
>   Checking Chef version...
>   Installing Berkshelf cookbooks to 'cookbooks'...
>   Resolving cookbook dependencies...
>   Uploading the kitchen...
>   WARNING: Local cookbook_path '/Users/username/chef-test/cookbooks' does not exist
>   Generating solo config...
>   Running Chef...
>   Starting Chef Client, version 12.0.0
>   Compiling Cookbooks...
>   Converging 4 resources
>   Recipe: apache::default
>     * yum_package[httpd] action install (up to date)
>     * service[httpd] action enable (up to date)
>     * service[httpd] action start (up to date)
>   Recipe: mysql::default
>     * yum_package[mysql-server] action install (up to date)
>     * service[mysqld] action enable (up to date)
>     * service[mysqld] action start (up to date)
>   Running handlers:
>   Running handlers complete
>   Chef Client finished, 0/6 resources updated in 3.239891356 seconds
>   $ ls -al
>   total 32
>   drwxr-xr-x  12 username  staff   408 12  7 19:12 .
>   drwxr-xr-x+ 26 username  staff   884 12  7 19:09 ..
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 .chef
>   -rw-r--r--   1 username  staff    12 12  7 19:11 .gitignore
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 21:52 .vagrant
>   -rw-r--r--   1 username  staff    41 12  7 00:34 Berksfile
>   -rw-r--r--   1 username  staff  4818 12  6 21:52 Vagrantfile
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 data_bags
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 environments
>   drwxr-xr-x   4 username  staff   136 12  7 19:09 nodes
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 username  staff   102 12  6 22:04 roles
>   drwxr-xr-x   6 username  staff   204 12  7 01:48 site-cookbooks
>   $

Would be nice to know what kind of settings does chef requires to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late late answer, however, if anyone else comes across this problem, try running the command: bundle exec berks install

Run it on your local machine of course!

This will download the cookbooks again or copy them again.

After that try to run: bundle exec knife solo bootstrap root@YOURSERVERIP

-> replace obviously your username@serverip with the real params.